# Is 3dprinting.stackexchange.com likely to still be active in the foreseeable future?

Tags: discussion

Is the Stack Exchange 3d printing site likely to remain active in the foreseeable future?

There seem to be some challenges, e.g. competition with the likes of Reddit, the change of management with the sale of Stack Exchange.

Comment: All answers will be speculation, that being said, the quality and format of different alternatives is not that good. I've followed Reddit for a while, many answers aren't that great or helpful and sometimes even incorrect.

Comment: I don't see any reason to expect that our metrics will change unexpectedly... what am I missing?

Comment: @Davo For those with a reputation over 5k, [site-analytics](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) shows it is more or less increasing over the years (discarding the [recent drop](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381668/google-analytics-4-ga4-upgrade) as a recent change to Google Analytics 4).

Answer (score 3):

As we are out of beta, it is unlikely that we will be "cancelled". However, regardling the sale of SE, that was over a year ago, it is probably best to refer to [What does the recent sale of Stack Exchange mean for the community?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/365050/280335) Only the new owners would know for sure what their intentions are, anything else would be pure speculation.

With respect to Reddit, as 0scar has stated, it doesn't seem to be much of a threat given the quality of questions, answers and advice given. Unless you are aware of any specific challenges relating to Reddit - that you allude to in your question, but don't provide any evidence of (do you have any links or references to are cause for concern?).

Nevertheless, that doesn't mean to say that there isn't the possibility of a vastly superior knowledge base emerging in the future... established players in a particular field can, and often do, change - after all, who remembers "Wang" these days?

The main problem at the moment seems to be the perceived drop off in visits and posts (be that real or imaginary, see [What caused our site's traffic to drop by 75% starting from May 11th?](https://stackoverflow.com/c/moderators/q/4631/412)). There certainly *seem* to be a ***lot*** fewer posts, as well as less activity, on this site since the late spring of 2022.

Comment: To comment on the fewer post, there has always been a variable sinusoid curve peaking around Christmas, looking at the weekly posted questions there are a little less questions, but isn't that expected. With good questions we gain a vast base which doesn't require people to post their own questions, they might have found the answer already! Personally I find it harder and harder to think of original questions to add to our knowledgebase to share my experience.

Comment: Also, looking at the changing world, people (especially the younger generation when looking at my kids) want video's while old timers like me prefer a webpage with text. I simply cannot get used to watching a video over and over rewinding to find out what the poster did or meant. But I might be one of the few... hence the diminishing amount of questions.